# How to unintegrate jprofile with netbeans

Tags: ide, netbeans-6.9, jprofiler

I installed jprofile to investigate a memory leak and also clicked the integrate IDE with netbeans 6.9.1. Runing my Web application worked well when clicking the Profile Project, However, when I want to debug again the project the jprofile is still being run when I just want to debug [i.e. Clicking the debug button instead of Profile]. This causes the debugging to fail all the time.

Glassfish Server Output Console.

```
JProfiler> Protocol version 33
JProfiler> Using JVMTI
JProfiler> JVMTI version 1.1 detected.
JProfiler> 32-bit library
JProfiler> Listening on port: 33200.
JProfiler> Instrumenting native methods.
JProfiler> Can retransform classes.
JProfiler> Can retransform any class.
JProfiler> Native library initialized
JProfiler> VM initialized
JProfiler> Waiting for a connection from the JProfiler GUI ...
```

I did not said to profile but still this log shows in the console. I tried to look at any uninstall or unintegrate option within the jprofile and there is non. But the jprofile is also not registered as a plugin when looking at the Tools > Plugins menu. Is there a way to unintegrate jprofile?

Note: I already grepped the whole "C:\Program Files\Netbeans 6.9.1\" folder and already removed the xml config of jprofile plus the jar inside the "modules\" folder. But after restarting netbeans and clicking debug button. It still shows the JProfiler prompt.
1. \NetBeans 6.9.1\ide\config\Modules\com-jprofiler-integrations-netbeans.xml
2. \NetBeans 6.9.1\ide\update\backup\netbeans\config\Modules\com-jprofiler-integrations-netbeans.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debugging should not append the VM parameter for profiling (-agentpath) to the java command, even if the JProfiler integration is installed, so this sounds kind of strange.

Look into the %USERPROFILE%.netbeans\6.9\modules directory and delete com-jprofiler-integrations-netbeans.jar. If that file does not exist either, the -agentpath parameter is added in a different way, maybe explicitly in your debug configuration.